# What distributions don't follow the central limit theorem?

Tags: distributions, central-limit-theorem, cauchy-distribution

The regularity restrictions for the CLT aren't that strong, it seems.  As a result, most sums of iid RVs converge toward a normal distribution.

I know there are examples that fail.  The Cauchy distribution is one.  But, if I recall, the sum of Cauchy RVs is also Cauchy.

It would seem at first blush that any distribution that could be crafted that fails the CLT must be idempotent in this way; there needs to be some 'terminal' distribution that is an attractor to which sums converge.

My questions:

1) Is this assumption correct?

2) What other distributions (other than Cauchy) meet this criteria, or fail to conform to the CLT?

Comment: If you know the regularity conditions for a particular CLT (there are several of them), you can guess that a distribution that doesn't satisfy them is likely to fail (it would have to fail all the CLTs at once, but the regularity conditions overlap a lot.)  An obvious one is that there actually has to be a finite second moment; if the variance is infinite or doesn't exist, the appropriately-scaled sums won't converge to a Normal distribution.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution#A_generalized_central_limit_theorem

Comment: There are many heavy-tailed distributions in the family of stable distributions that follow stable law conversion but not converging to a normal distribution.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution

Answer (score 1):

This is an example taken from Lehmann's "Elements of large sample theory"

[image]